# Parity of a Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Determine the parity of the following.

$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 2 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

Workings:

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 7 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$

The parity is odd.

I'm wondering if this is correct.

Comment: Thats correct. What is the question?

Comment: I meant to ask if what I sad was correct. But I forgot to write it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $\sigma$ must be miscopied. It isn't a permutation (both 1 and 4 map to 2 and 1 isn't an output -- it's not a bijection).

Comment: @BillCook Right $4$ was supposed to go to $1$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\tau=\beta_{1}\cdots \beta_{k}$ where each $\beta_{i}$, for $1\le i \le k$, is a transposition, then we have $$sgn(\tau)=(-1)^{k}$$
But, for $\sigma$ we have $k=5$. Hence, $$sgn(\sigma)=(-1)^{5}=-1.$$

Comment: No problem! If you have any questions about this just let know :)